# Sine defined for a triangle inscribed in a circle with a diameter of one

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

Let a circle be drawn with a diameter of one (and thus a radius of one half). Then let a triangle with vertices A, B, and C be inscribed in the circle (i.e. points A, B, and C are arbitrary points on the circle).

Then a, the side of the triangle opposite angle A is equal to sin(A)

Likewise, b=sin(B) and c=sin(c). I have attempted to find or devise a proof of this, but I don't know where to start!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

Comment: This is a very nicely laid out question, but you need to give a context as well. Is it a homework question? What level mathematics course is it for? Perhaps an example of a theorem you're allowed to use that you've studied recently?

Comment: It is not a homework problem, it is something i saw in the book "The mathematics of the heavens and the earth: The history of early trigonometry" by Glenn Van Brummelen. I understand that the circle with a diameter of one serves as a model for the law of sines, what I do not understand is why sin(A)=a, sin(B)=b when the diameter of the circle is one.

Answer (score 3):

Although lab bhattacharjee has already said, we have to use the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Proof). If you aren't familiar with it or its proof, see the link. I will tell you how to proceed in a detailed manner.

[image]

Here we have our $\triangle ABC$ and its circumscribed circle with center $O$. We now construct a diameter $BOD$. So, $\angle BAC=\angle BDC$ and $\angle BCD=90^{\circ}$. Now,
$$\sin\angle A=\sin\angle BDC=\frac{a}{2r}$$

Where, $a=BC$ and $r$ is the radius. You can similarly draw conclusions for $\angle B$ and $\angle C$. This gives rise to what we call the, extended law of sines:
$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=D$$

Where $D$ is the diameter of the circumradius. It is a very useful theorem, and applying to your triangle gives:

$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=1$$

Done! There is one caveat though, we did not prove the extended law of sines for right triangles [it should be obvious] and obtuse triangles. However, we can it do it similarly, and I leave the proof as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

As lab bhattacharjee pointed out, what you just described is the law of sines, and it applies to all triangles. Google "law of sines proof" for more info.